# How to use SQL Update function in bash script

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I am trying to do an Update into a SQL DB via a bash script when a variable is greater than another variable, but I can't seem to get it working.

I use a standard script using update which works normally but i can't get it working with the greater than another variable for some reason.

```
#!/bin/bash
SQL="UPDATE stocklog.stock SET order = 'NEWTEST' WHERE stock.currentstock >= stock.optimalstock"

MYSQL_USER="****"
MYSQL_PASS="****"
MYSQL_DB="****"

echo $SQL | /usr/bin/mysql --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS $MYSQL_DB
```

If I instead state currentstock is equal to '1', the same Update command works in the bash script.

Error that it gives out is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order = 'NEWTEST' WHERE stock.currentstock >= stock.optimalstock' at line 1
```

The working SQL command I am trying to do is:

```
UPDATE `stocklog`.`stock` SET `order` = 'NEWTEST' WHERE `stock`.`currentstock` >= `stock`.`optimalstock`;
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I need to do here to get it working? 
Sorry if its a rubbish question, I'm still trying to learn!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out!
Nothing was wrong with the method of doing it, I played around with another script I have that works fine and applied the same methodology to this.
In the end I tried renaming the DB column to orderstatus instead of order and this worked.

So it seems likes 'order' must mean something within the SQL command within a bash script?

Thanks for your help @Jerry M

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SQL="UPDATE stocklog.stock SET order = 'NEWTEST' WHERE stock.currentstock >= stock.optimalstock"
```

to

```
SQL="UPDATE 'stocklog'.'stock' SET 'order' = 'NEWTEST' WHERE 'stock'.'currentstock' >= 'stock'.'optimalstock';"
```

`echo $SQL` produces:

> UPDATE 'stocklog'.'stock' SET `order` = 'NEWTEST' WHERE
>   'stock'.'currentstock' >= 'stock'.'optimalstock';

which matches what you requested.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, tried that but still get an error:

    ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\''.

Comment: Is it the same error? What does `echo $SQL` give you after changing the statement? Is it what you expected?

Comment: Different error to what I was getting before, It doesn't make the required changes when executing it if that is what you mean?

Comment: I meant, you posted that you are trying to get your `SQL` variable to look like this: `UPDATE `stocklog`.`stock` SET `order` = 'NEWTEST' WHERE `stock`.`currentstock` >= `stock`.`optimalstock`;` . Does it look like that? What is the different error? It may be that my suggestion fixed the first thing and the second error deserves a second question

Comment: Okay, just showing the output on the echo shows it as:UPDATE \'stocklog\'.\'stock\' SET \'order\' = \'SLASHTEST\' WHERE \'stock\'.\'currentstock\' >= \'stock\'.\'optimalstock\';

Comment: Hi Jerry, apologies had to get off. Unfortunatley not, same error as in my initial description:ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''stocklog'.'stock' SET order = '' WHERE 'stock'.'currentstock' >= 'stock'.'optim' at line 1

Comment: Interesting. But you said simply copying and pasting that SQL code works? From what I can tell, it creates a `$SQL` variable exactly how you specified

Comment: Correct if I use the SQL input that i put in my description, into the SQL database manually, it completes with no issues

Comment: Oh, I see an error. Try again now. Sorry for holdup, @StevenRothera

Comment: Thats okay i appreciate the help! Unfortunately still a no go.
Error: ./orderstatusremove.sh: line 2: order: command not found
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''stocklog'.'stock' SET = 'NEWTEST' WHERE 'stock'.'currentstock' >= 'stock'.'opti' at line 1

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: How does the result of `SQL="UPDATE 'stocklog'.'stock' SET 'order' = 'NEWTEST' WHERE 'stock'.'currentstock' >= 'stock'.'optimalstock';"` differ from your SQL statement that works?